# Many to many with additional fields

Tags: symfony

I have two entities:

- Questionnaire
- Page

This entities have a many to many relation. But i would like to add a third field in my Many To Many Relation table , which called "sorting".

My solution was to create three entities

- Questionnaire
- Page
- QuestionnairePage

The entities Questionnaire and Page have a one to many relation to entity QuestionnairePage and the additional field sorting exists in my new entity "QuestionnairePage".

But i have the following issue. If i pass a Questionnaire object to my twig template to render all Pages (example Page titles), i can't access my Page object, i can only access the QuestionnairePage.page object, which was a id. But i need the Page object.

My twig template look like

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ questionnaire.title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ questionnaire.subtitle }}</h2>
    <p>{{ questionnaire.description | raw }}</p>

    {% for p in questionnaire.questionnairePage %}
        {{p.id}} // This the QuestionnairePage.page.id
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Can someone give me a hint, how can i solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `getQuestionnaire()` method (which will return `$this->questionnaire`) to your `QuestionnairePage` entity and use it in twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ questionnaire.title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ questionnaire.subtitle }}</h2>
    <p>{{ questionnaire.description | raw }}</p>

    {% for p in questionnaire.questionnairePage %}
        {{p.questionare}} // This should be the Questionnaire object
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```